# Alternative ways to say "what's that?"

Tags: translation

What does the character say in this video? It's translated as "what's that?" . I would expect him to say, nanda kore, nani kore,nanda kore wa, sore wa nan desu ka, , kore wa nan desu ka or something like that but what I hear is

"nanda (unintelligible word) wa"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_vqJGKvn5k#t=5m57s

Comment: Sounds like he says, 「なんだ、あれは？」 (inverted order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He says "なんだ、あれは".  It's the same meaning as 'あれはなんだ', 'あれはなんですか'.  'これ' means 'this',  'あれ' means 'that' (something not nearby).